# i++ on if condition doesn't work

Tags: php, html, if-statement, while-loop

My question is,

I am trying to loop through my code **if** it finds a record where 'weekdag' is correct. I guess my code is getting stuck because it is in my if statement but i really need it there. What is the solution?

```
<?php

$i = 0;
while ($i <= 6) {

    $weekdag = mysql_result($result, $i, "weekdag");

    if ($i == 1) {

        if ($weekdag == "1") {
            echo "<td><input name='weekdag1' value='1' type='checkbox' onChange='this.form.submit()' checked><input name='weekdag10' type='hidden' value='1'></td>";
            $i++;
        } else {
            echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='addweek' value='1' onChange='this.form.submit()'></td>";
        }

        if ($weekdag == "2") {
            echo "<td><input name='weekdag2' value='2' type='checkbox' onChange='this.form.submit()' checked><input name='weekdag20' type='hidden' value='2'></td>";
            $i++;
        } else {
            echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='addweek' value='2' onChange='this.form.submit()'></td>";
        }

        if ($weekdag == "3") {
            echo "<td><input name='weekdag3' value='3' type='checkbox' onChange='this.form.submit()' checked><input name='weekdag30' type='hidden' value='3'></td>";
            $i++;
        } else {
            echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='addweek' value='3' onChange='this.form.submit()'></td>";
        }

        if ($weekdag == "4") {
            echo "<td><input name='weekdag4' value='4' type='checkbox' onChange='this.form.submit()' checked><input name='weekdag40' type='hidden' value='4'></td>";
            $i++;
        } else {
            echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='addweek' value='4' onChange='this.form.submit()'></td>";
        }

        if ($weekdag == "5") {
            echo "<td><input name='weekdag5' value='5' type='checkbox' onChange='this.form.submit()' checked><input name='weekdag50' type='hidden' value='5'></td>";
            $i++;
        } else {
            echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='addweek' value='5' onChange='this.form.submit()'></td>";
        }

        if ($weekdag == "6") {
            echo "<td><input name='weekdag6' value='6' type='checkbox' onChange='this.form.submit()' checked><input name='weekdag60' type='hidden' value='6'></td>";
            $i++;
        } else {
            echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='addweek' value='6' onChange='this.form.submit()'></td>";
        }

        if ($weekdag == "7") {
            echo "<td><input name='weekdag7' value='7' type='checkbox' onChange='this.form.submit()' checked><input name='weekdag70' type='hidden' value='7'></td>";
            $i++;
        } else {
            echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='addweek' value='7' onChange='this.form.submit()'></td>";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Dont downvote a question just because it appears so simple to you. Everybody starts with simple questions, you also did.

Comment: I think the whole thing that’s tried here is wrong, and rather should be instructed how to actually do this properly... But that’s out of scope of the question that to be honest doesn’t make much sense to me.

Comment: I am trying to find a hit and if it finds one, loop. For example my $i = 1. I want to look inside this $i = 1, where a number of 'weekdag' is hidden. For example the number is 3. So I am going to find it. If weekdag=1 {} else {}, If weekdag=2 {} else {}, If weekdag=3 (YES THERE IT IS NOW LOOP!!!) {} else {}. Why I want the code to do this is if it finds a hit I don't want the rest in this case weekdag=4, weekdag=5, weekdag=6, weekdag=7 to be executed

Answer (score 2):

In the first loop,

```
$i = 0
```

and it does NOT get increased, because the if-statement is ONLY for `$i=1`.
So it is an endless loop.

Maybe you need:

```
if ($i == 1) {
  //...
}
else
{
  $i++;
}
```

Comment: @chiastic-security well, no, because if OP transfers all code that was inside `if ($i == 1) {...}` before then it will get incremented. (provided `$weekdag` is in range {"1"..."7"})

Comment: So it has to work when i change $i = 0 to $i = 1, right? I don't know if the goal I am trying to reach is clear but i just need to increase my loop when one of the if-statements finds a combined record

Comment: @DrCopyPaste Ah, yes, I think all that `$i++;` stuff inside the conditional statements wants to come out. At the moment it's just a convoluted way of adding one on each iteration, except that it'll fail if `$weekdag` isn't in range.

Answer (score 0):

I see two challenges here;

- Your actual issue
- The amount of repeated code

Here's what I've done

```
$i = 0;
while($i <= 6) {

    $weekdag = mysql_result($result, $i, "weekdag");

    $weekdag10 = $i * 10;

    if($i == 1) {
        if($weekdag == $i) {
            echo "<td><input name='weekdag". $i ."' value='". $i ."' type='checkbox' onChange='this.form.submit()' checked><input name='weekdag". $weekdag10 ."' type='hidden' value='". $i ."'></td>";
            $i++;
        } else {
            echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='addweek' value='". $i ."' onChange='this.form.submit()'></td>";
        }
    }

}
```

#### Edits

- Changed code to run with this logic: [i++ on if condition doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25446103/i-on-if-condition-doesnt-work/25446285#comment39702296_25446130)

## After reading answer comments

> Not getting there yet. I am sorry if im irritating you. I will try to explain further more. I am trying to find a hit, for example my $i = 1. I want to look inside this $i = 1, where a number of 'weekdag' is hidden. For example the number is 3. So I am going to find it. If weekdag=1 {} else {}, If weekdag=2 {} else {}, If weekdag=3 (YES THERE IT IS NOW LOOP!!!) {} else {}. Why I want the code to do this is if it finds a hit I don't want the rest in this case weekdag=4, weekdag=5, weekdag=6, weekdag=7 to be executed

Then perhaps something like this;

```
$weekdag = mysql_result($result, $i, "weekdag");
//A list of all available $weekdags
$arrWeekdags = array(1,2,3,4,5,6);

if( in_array($weekdag, $arrWeekdags) ) {
    //We have found a match!
    echo "<td><input name='weekdag". $weekdag ."' value='". $weekdag ."' type='checkbox' onChange='this.form.submit()' checked><input name='weekdag". ($weekdag * 10) ."' type='hidden' value='". $weekdag ."'></td>";

    //Remove it from the list of available weekdags
    unset($arrWeekdags[$weekdag]);
}

foreach($arrWeekdags as $intWeekdag) {
    echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='addweek' value='". $intWeekdag ."' onChange='this.form.submit()'></td>";
}
```

Comment: Not getting there yet. I am sorry if im irritating you. I will try to explain further more. I am trying to find a hit, for example my $i = 1. I want to look inside this $i = 1, where a number of 'weekdag' is hidden. For example the number is 3. So I am going to find it. If weekdag=1 {} else {}, If weekdag=2 {} else {}, If weekdag=3 (YES THERE IT IS NOW LOOP!!!) {} else {}. Why I want the code to do this is if it finds a hit I don't want the rest in this case weekdag=4, weekdag=5, weekdag=6, weekdag=7 to be executed

Answer (score 0):

You're never increasing the value of `i`, so it's eternally stuck on 0. Try adding `$i++;` at the very end of the loop:

```
if ($i == 1) {
  //...
}
$i++;
```

and removing all the `$i++;` from your conditional statements.

Answer (score 0):

Increase the $i before while's end, it has to be increased everytime.

```
 while ($i <= 6) {
      if ($i == 1) {
        ....
      } 

      $i++;
 }
```

Comment: I only want to increase the $i when the **if** statement is succeed

Comment: If you only increase when the `if` statement succeeds, then it'll be stuck for ever when the `if` statement fails!

Comment: exactly as @chiastic-security has said.

Comment: btw, if you want to increase it when if is succeed, start $i = 1 instead of $i = 0, no?